# Reverse coding a likert-scale variable in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R so this might be a simple answer. I am trying to alter my variable so that it reads as "strongly support" = 4 "slightly support" = 3 "slightly oppose" = 2 "strongly oppose" = 1

Currently, it is coded as "strongly support" = 1 "slightly support" = 2 "slightly oppose" = 3 "strongly oppose" = 4

Basically, I am trying to flip the response values

I do not have tidyverse and for some reason I haven't been able to install it; so preferably this would use survey or datasets or something else that is super basic

Comment: Can you share the input in reproducible form? Add output of `dput(x)` at end of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
scale <- c("strongly support" = 1, "slightly support" = 2, "slightly oppose" = 3, "strongly oppose" = 4)
revert_scale <- -scale + max(scale) + 1
revert_scale
strongly support slightly support  slightly oppose  strongly oppose 
               4                3                2                1
```